# Divide a number to many groups based on several factor using Python

Tags: python

I have retail sales data of the whole Germany, for example beer revenue. Now I want to find a way to divide that number into 596 cities of Germany based on the GDP per capita of each city and consumer spending of each city. So after that I can have the beer revenue of each single city in Germany.

My assumption is: city beer = city consumer spending * x + city GDP per cap * y. and then sum of city beer = national beer

Could you please advice which kind of algorithm or a way to do it in Python?
Thank you so much.

Comment: There's a lot of assumptions that will need to be made to handle this. If you make certain assumptions (like that beer spending is proportional to GDP), it's pretty trivial: `city_beer = national_beer * city_gdp / national_gdp`. If you make different assumptions, you'll need a different equation. There's not really an algorithm for this, it's likely just arithmetic after you establish your assumptions (though maybe some set of assumptions could require some numerical analysis to solve, but I can't imagine what those assumptions would be).

Comment: My assumption is: city beer = city consumer spending * x + city GDP per cap * y. and then sum of city beer = national beer

Comment: create a function that takes "city consumer spending" and "city GDP per capita" as parameters. Assuming that x and y are some constants that would be constant for all cities, you can store them in 2 variables at global scope or else if x and y are also different for different cities, then pass them too as arguments to your function. The way you would store the values that you would pass to this function would depend on your application. You may want to have it in a configuration file or a dat file or even in a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is not so good. Some cities may spend a bigger fraction of their total consumation in beer.

I think a better assumption is that it's a variable fraction of the total consumation in beer, let's say, city i consumes a fraction xi of national consumation in beer, where xi is somehow dependent on the GDP and on the city consumation.

To find xi, firstly scale the GDP to be in [delta, 1-delta], where delta is a positive quantity very close to zero, and keep their relative order. To do that, consider the biggest GDP is GDPmax and the minimum GDP is GDPmin. Then, map each GDPi to

scaleGDPi = [(GDPi - GDPmin) * (1 - 2 * delta)/(GDPmax-GDPmin)] + delta.

In a similar way, also scale the consumation to be in [delta, 1 - delta].

Then, consider xi = scaleGDPi * scaleConsumationi * x and you get (city beer)i = scaleGDPi * scaleConsumationi * x * national beer

By imposing that the sum of city beer is equal to national beer, you get:

x = 1 / (sum scaleGDPi * scaleConsumationi).

So, city beer = (scaleGDPi * scaleConsumationi * national beer)/(sum scaleGDPi * scaleConsumationi).

I think this would be a more adequate modelization of your problem.

Comment: May I ask which logic behind the equation: scalei = [(GDPi - GDPmin) * (1 - 2 * delta)/(GDPmax-GDPmin)] + delta.

Comment: Sure, this formula scales your set of GDPs while keeping their relative order. Initially I thought in letting them in the interval [0, 1]. But this way, the minimum GDP would be mapped to zero and wouldn't contribute at all for the beer consumption, what doesn't make much sense. So, I scaled them to be in the interval [delta, 1-delta], with delta very close to zero instead. This way, every city has some contribution

Comment: To get the formula that scale the GDPs, I applied a simple proportion rule. The proportion of the segment [GDPmin, GDPi] with respect to the total segment [GDPmin, GDPmax], is (GDPi - GDPmin)/(GDPmax - GDPmin).

I want the proportion of segment [mapped(GDPmin), mapped(GDPi)] with respect to the segment [mapped(GDPmin), mapped(GDPmax)] to be equal to the first proportion. 

That's:


(scalei - delta)/((1-delta) - delta) = (GDPi - GDPmin)/(GDPmax - GDPmin)

Comment: oh, that means it is similar to the Minmaxscaler idea. Do you think we can use Z-score normalization instead?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Anything that scales your GDPs to [0, 1] while keeping their relative order would be fine in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense to scale it. But I also think that GDP is not the most important thing. For example, some cities might have lower GDP than other cities but their consumer spending on beer still higher than some other cities. SO I also want to consider both factors in my calculation. But I have no clue if considering 2 factor togerther when dividing data

Comment: Yes, that is true. How about also scaling the cities consumption and make the city beer equal the multiplication of the two factors times a constant, which you encounter by imposing that the sum is equal the total ?

Comment: I will edit my answer to consider that

Comment: @Ng.Alina Consider my updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246429/discussion-between-john-doe-and-ng-alina).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have sales data in some file text or csv with some columns based on what we can divide the rows in cities.

So you can read this file line by line and add the records in dictionary and the key to this dictionary is your city name or city id and values can be list of list of sales data belong to that city.
So now this dictionary will have all your sales data divided in city.
It should be something like

```
dict = {
  'city1': [[col1,col2,col3],[col1,col2,col3],[col1,col2,col3]],
  'city2': [[col1,col2,col3],[col1,col2,col3],[col1,col2,col3]]
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but my question is how to divide the total sales of Germany to single city based on GDP per cap and consumer spending of each city. For example, beer sales of the whole Germany is 1 billion USD, how to estimate the beer sales of each city if we use GDP and consumer spending of each single city